# Is There Anything Wrong With My Code. The bot is online and has every perm but still will not respond to -ping command

Tags: javascript

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

const prefix = '-';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

I dont know what is wrong, im new to coding so this is just experimenting. Like i said in the title it allows me to run node . and in cmd says ready but when i go to discord it just doesnt respond. Like i said it is online and has all perms.

Comment: Do you call it from Discord App?

Answer (score 0):

You need the `GUILD_MESSAGES` and `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intents as well.

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });
```

Also make sure that you enabled the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` privilege for your bot at: https://discord.com/developers/applications

Image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVSXE.jpg